# read two files and filter second file based on a column of first file

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

I have an input file containing the keywords and have csv file that needs to be filtered on those keywords.

Here is my attempt to automate task using python.

```
import csv
with open('Input.txt', 'rb') as InputFile:
    with open('28JUL2017.csv', 'rb') as CM_File:
        read_Input=csv.reader(InputFile)
        for row1 in csv.reader(InputFile):
            #print row1

            read_CM=csv.reader(CM_File)
            next(read_CM, None)
            for row2 in csv.reader(CM_File):
                #print row2
                if row1[0] == row2[0] :

                    Output= row2[0]+","+row2[1]+","+row2[5]+","+row2[6]
                    print Output
```

I get just the first row from the file to be filtered. Tried various things but could not understand where I am going wrong. Please point the mistake for me here.

Comment: You need to rewind (or close and reopen) the `CM_File` in order to read it more than once with the `csv.reader`. It would be more efficient to read all the keywords in at once and create a `set` of them, and then read the `CM_File` once and check to see if _any_ of the keywords are in each row as it's read.

Comment: If you need data from a file multiple times, read it all into a string or list that you can parse several times.  File objects aren't like doobies to be passed around.  Your logic should be: 1) read the first file 2) close the first file 3) read the second file 4) compare the data from first file with data from second file 5) do stuff to second file 6) close second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_Input` and `read_CM` are essentially iterators. Once you loop over them  - you are done: you cannot iterate twice. If you insist on doing your way, then you have to rewind to the beginning of the file each time you want to start a new loop and "re-read" the CSV file. Here is a fix:

```
import csv
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as InputFile:
    with open('file2.csv', 'rb') as CM_File:
        read_Input=csv.reader(InputFile)
        for row1 in csv.reader(InputFile):
            CM_File.seek(0) # rewind to the beginning of the file
            read_CM=csv.reader(CM_File)
            next(read_CM, None)
            for row2 in csv.reader(CM_File):
                if row1[0] == row2[0] :
                    Output= row2[0]+","+row2[1]+","+row2[5]+","+row2[6]
                    print Output
```

Instead of this, I would suggest that you loop over already read lines instead of *re-reading* files. Also, instead of having nested loops, create a list of "keywords" and simply check that `row2[0]` is in that list:

```
import csv
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as InputFile:
    with open('file2.csv', 'rb') as CM_File:
        read_Input = csv.reader(InputFile) # read file only once
        keywords = [rec[0] for rec in read_Input]
        read_CM = csv.reader(CM_File) # read file only once
        next(read_CM, None) # not sure why you do this? to skip first line?
        for row2 in read_CM:
            if row2[0] in keywords:
                Output = row2[0]+","+row2[1]+","+row2[5]+","+row2[6]
                print("Output: {}".format(Output))
```

Comment: making changes  you suggested yielded zero results. the first row that I was getting is also gone. would it help if i add some sample data ?

Comment: Of course some data would definitely be helpful. Also expected result wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @user3017186 I have edited my answer based on testing with two test files.

Comment: this works perfectly well.
my work file has an header row. to skip reading it, using next(read_CM, None)
Thanks @agn-gazer you have been very helpful